# How to query with All, Any and None conditions on the same MySQL table?

Tags: mysql

I have a table that is an index of content IDs and category IDs. There is a 1:many relationship between the content and the categories, so multiple rows for each content ID.

I need to search for content based on the following criteria:
- the content contains ALL categories in list-1 of category IDs
- the content contain ANY category id within list-2 of category IDs
- the content contains NONE of the categories in list-3 of category IDs

I'm uncertain whether I should use joins for the ALL condition and LEFT JOINS for the ANY and NONE conditions, rejecting any rows where the NONE term values are not null, or whether there's a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I see you should use a `UNION` in this case like

```
select * from content_table
where content in (list-1 of category IDs)

UNION

select * from content_table
where content in (list-2 of category IDs)

UNION

select * from content_table
where content not in (list-3 of category IDs);
```

Comment: I understand your intent, but I don't see anything in that which differentiates the first select being an AND requirement (the content must contain X and Y and Z) from the second select which would be an OR requirement (the content can contain X or Y or Z)

Comment: @Ayen, with `ALL` in your first query, are you going to get the list-1 from some other table; if so then you can use MySQL `ALL` operator. Otherwise currently the query performs a `ANY` -> `ANY` -> `NONE`

Comment: The flow is that a HTTP POST request is received containing parameters, including 3 arrays, each being one of those lists. Which had me notice that I forgot to mention that there would never be an ANY -and- ALL query (ANY would make no sense in the presence of ALL) - it would be one or the other.